# How to use deviceType=Tablet for testing on desktop with Cordova included?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, cordova, sencha-touch-2.1

You can append `deviceType=Phone` or deviceType=Tablet to simulate different device types like this `/index.html?deviceType=Tablet` when testing on Sencha Touch 2.1 app on desktopC. This works fine without Cordova included in your Sencha Touch 2.1 project. However when cordova (PhoneGap) is included it doesn't go anywhere and get stuck on loading screen without any error messages whatsoever.

Is there anyway to test on desktop with Cordova included? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

create a test build with a script included that redirects the page:

`document.location.ref=app.html?deviceType=Tablet;`

aka just put that in a js file and include the file.